# MLE on a restricted paraameter space and its behavior

Tags: probability, maximum-likelihood

Suppose $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are a random sample from a normal distribution with mean $\theta$ and variance 1. Find the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$, under the restriction that $\theta\geqslant 0$.

I have found the MLE when there is no restriction on $\theta$.

$\hat{\theta}=\bar{X}$.

How would I incorporate the restriction $\theta \geqslant 0$ and whether the new MLE will be unbiased and consistent or not?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Answer (score 2):

Maximum (quasi) likelihood estimate is a point $\hat{\theta}$ that maximizes likelihood of the data over the sample of possible values of $\theta$ $\Theta$.

In your case it seems to be that if the true $\theta_0 \geq 0$, then your estimate will be asymptotically unbiased and consistent.

It is OK to consider a restricted version of MLE even if true $\theta_0 < 0$ you will get an asymptotically unbiased and consistent estimate for the point $\theta^*$ that minimises KL between true $p_{\theta_0}$ and $\{p_{\theta}, \theta \in \Theta\}$ with in your case $\Theta = \{\theta \geq 0\}$.
From formula for KL divergence for two normal distributions it follows that $\theta^* = 0$ in this case.

Obviously, if true $\theta_0 < 0$, you can not get unbiased estimate in a common sense using such a restriction.